# Access nested web user control elements

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a nested web user control. Main web user control I have used on a page but now I want to access the control inside the inner web user control and its events.
Can any body help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent user control, expose a reference to your child control, or it's properties through a property. For example

```
public partial class ParentControl : UserControl
{
    ...
    // Expose the whole child control
    public ChildControl MyChild
    {
        get { return this.theIdOfTheChildControl; }
    }

    ...

    // or expose specific properties
    public string MyChildText
    {
        get { return this.theIdOfTheChildControl.Text; }
        set { this.theIdOfTheChildControl.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
        private List<Control> GetAllNestedUserControl(Control ph)
    {
        List<Control> Get = new List<Control>();
        foreach (var control in ph.Controls)
        {
            if (control is UserControl)
            {
                UserControl uc = control as UserControl;
                if (uc.HasControls())
                {
                   Get =  GetAllNestedUserControl(uc);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Control c = (Control)control;
                if (!(control is LiteralControl))
                {
                     Get.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }
        return Get;
    }
```

this method will return the list of all controls then do the following to get the control u want

```
        List<Control> Get = GetAllNestedUserControl(ph);
        Label l = (Label)Get.Find(o => o.ID == "lblusername");
        l.Text = "changed from master";
```